# Converting non digit text to double and then back to string

Tags: c#, arrays, converters

I have a unique situation where I have to write code on top of an already establish platform so I am trying to figure out a hack to make something work.

The problem I have is I have a user defined string.  Basically naming a signal.  I need to get this into another program but the only method available is within a double value.  Below is what I have tried but not been able to get it to work.  I tried converting the string to byte array and then creating a new string by looping the bytes.  Then I convert this string to a Double.  Then use BitCoverter to get it back to byte array and then try to get the string.

Not sure if this can even be achieve.  Any ideas?

```
string signal = "R3MEXA";
string newId = "1";

byte[] asciiBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signal);

foreach (byte b in asciiBytes)
    newId += b.ToString();

double signalInt = Double.Parse(newId);

byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(signalInt);

string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Why not use a string to byte array, and then foreach byte in Byte[] Convert.ToDouble(byte)

Comment: What is the 'range' of your signal string, e.g. longest string, shortest string, what characters, etc?

Comment: Have you tried to use `BitConverter.ToDouble` method right on your asciiBytes array? If you pad your array so that it has 8 bytes length then you don't need `newId`, `foreach` loop, and `Double.Parse(newId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your string consists of ASCII characters (7Bit):

Convert your string into a bit-Array, seven bits per character.

Convert this bit-array into a string of digits, using 3 bits for each digit. (there are digits 0..7)

Convert this string of digits to a double number.

Answer (score 0):

You initially set `newId` to `"1"`, which means when you're doing later conversion, you're not going to get the right output unless to account for the `"1"` again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because if you convert it back you don't know the length of a byte.
So I made every byte to a length of 3.

```
        string signal = "R3MEXA";
        string newId = "1";

        byte[] asciiBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signal);

        foreach (byte b in asciiBytes)
            newId += b.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'); //Add Zero, if the byte has less than 3 digits

        double signalInt = Double.Parse(newId);

        //Convert it back
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(); //Create a list, we don't know how many bytes will come (Or you calc it: maximum is _signal / 3)
        //string _signal = signalInt.ToString("F0"); //Maybe you know a better way to get the double to string without scientific
        //This is my workaround to get the integer part from the double:
        //It's not perfect, but  I don't know another way at the moment without losing information
        string _signal = "";
        while (signalInt > 1)
        {
            int _int = (int)(signalInt % 10);
            _signal += (_int).ToString();
            signalInt /= 10;
        }
        _signal = String.Join("",_signal.Reverse());
        for (int i = 1; i < _signal.Length; i+=3)
        {
            byte b = Convert.ToByte(_signal.Substring(i, 3)); //Make 3 digits to one byte
            if(b!=0) //With the ToString("F0") it is possible that empty bytes are at the end
            bytes.Add(b);
        }
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray()); //Yeah "R3MEX" The "A" is lost, because double can't hold that much.
```

---

## What can improved?

- Not every PadLeft is necessary. Work from back to front and if the third digit of a byte is greater than 2, you know, that the byte has only two digits. (Sorry for my english, I write an example).

### Example

```
194 | 68 | 75 | 13
194687513
Reverse:
315786491
31  //5 is too big    13
57  //8 is too big    75
86  //4 is too big    68
491 //1 is ok        194
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting a return of R3MEZ from result

Comment: I added a workaround, so you not losing information.